# Issue handling TComponent objects (TEdits, TLabels, ...) from a TForm object, saved in an unordered_map (member of my own class)

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I'm trying to handle `TComponent` objects (`TEdit`, `TLabel`, ...) from my `TForm` object which are saved in an `std::unordered_map`. But something weird happens to the pair values when I try to handle them.

Test.h

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef TestH
#define TestH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "Container.h"
#include "Handler.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TUMap_Test : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TEdit *Edit1;
    TEdit *Edit2;
    TEdit *Edit3;
    TEdit *Edit4;

    TLabel *Label1;
    TLabel *Label2;
    TLabel *Label3;
    TLabel *Label4;

    TButton *Button1;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);

private:    // User declarations
    Container Cont;

public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TUMap_Test(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TUMap_Test *UMap_Test;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

I made a `Container` class to pack those `TComponent` objects as follows:

Container.h

```cpp
#ifndef CONTAINERH
#define CONTAINERH

#include <vcl.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>

class Container{

private:

    TForm * m_Form;
    std::unordered_map<String, TEdit*> m_Edits;
    std::unordered_map<String, TLabel*> m_Labels;

    void packEdits();
    void packLabels();

public:
    Container(){}
    void packComponents(TForm * Form);

    std::unordered_map<String, TEdit*> * getEdits();
    std::unordered_map<String, TLabel*> * getLabels();

};

#endif
```

Container.cpp

```cpp
#include "Container.h"

void Container::packComponents(TForm * Form){
    m_Form = Form;
    packEdits();
    packLabels();
}

void Container::packEdits(){
    String Edits[4] = {"Edit1", "Edit2", "Edit3", "Edit4"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        m_Edits.insert(std::make_pair(Edits[i], dynamic_cast<TEdit*>(m_Form->FindComponent(Edits[i]))));
    }
}

void Container:: packLabels(){
    String Labels[4] = {"Edit1", "Edit2", "Edit3", "Edit4"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        m_Labels.insert(std::make_pair(Labels[i], dynamic_cast<TLabel*>(m_Form->FindComponent(Labels[i]))));
    }
}

std::unordered_map<String, TEdit*> * Container::getEdits(){
    return &m_Edits;
}

std::unordered_map<String, TLabel*> * Container::getLabels(){
    return &m_Labels;
}
```

Then I create a `Container` object named `Cont` in my `TForm` object. In order to pack those `TComponent` objects later, I had to use the `TForm` object as an argument of the `packComponents()` method (`packComponents(TForm * Form)`). Then I used `Form->FindComponent()` to insert my components into a `std::unordered_map`.

I made a handler function to handle my `TComponent` objects that are packed in a `std::unordered_map`:

Handler.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Container.h"
#include <vcl.h>

void TextEditsToLabels(Container * Cont);
```

Handler.cpp

```
#include "Handler.h"

void TextEditsToLabels(Container * Cont){
    //Change the Caption of Labels to Edits Text
    (*Cont->getLabels())["Label1"]->Caption = (*Cont->getEdits())["Edit1"]->Text;
        (*Cont->getLabels())["Label2"]->Caption = (*Cont->getEdits())["Edit2"]->Text;
    (*Cont->getLabels())["Label3"]->Caption = (*Cont->getEdits())["Edit3"]->Text;
    (*Cont->getLabels())["Label4"]->Caption = (*Cont->getEdits())["Edit4"]->Text;
}
```

Finally, in `Test.cpp`, I called the `packer()` function of my `Container` object, and then I made an event function on `Button1` to call the `TextEditsToLabels()` function.

Test.cpp

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Test.h"

#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"

TUMap_Test *UMap_Test;

fastcall TUMap_Test::TUMap_Test(TComponent* Owner): TForm(Owner){
    Cont.packComponents(this);
}

void __fastcall TUMap_Test::Button1Click(TObject *Sender){
    TextEditsToLabels(&Cont);
}
```

[image]

The problem is, when I click on `Button1`, nothing happens. So I put a breakpoint in my `TextEditsToLabels()` function to see what is happening, and made four variables to get the `Text` inside of those `TEdit`s. Those new variables show me NULL values:

```cpp
#include "Handler.h"

void TextEditsToLabels(Container * Cont){
    String Text1 = (*Cont->getEdits())["Edit1"]->Text;
    String Text2 = (*Cont->getEdits())["Edit2"]->Text;
    String Text3 = (*Cont->getEdits())["Edit3"]->Text;
    String Text4 = (*Cont->getEdits())["Edit4"]->Text;

    //BREAKPOINT


    //Change the Caption of Labels to Edits Text
    //(*Cont->getLabels())["Label1"]->Caption = (*Cont->getEdits())["Edit1"]->Text;
    //(*Cont->getLabels())["Label2"]->Caption = (*Cont->getEdits())["Edit2"]->Text;
    //(*Cont->getLabels())["Label3"]->Caption = (*Cont->getEdits())["Edit3"]->Text;
    //(*Cont->getLabels())["Label4"]->Caption = (*Cont->getEdits())["Edit4"]->Text;
}
```

[image]

Note: Before clicking on `Button1`, I put some random values in my `TEdit`, expecting to see them in my four new variables:

I tried to change the container type from `std::unordered_map` to `std::map`, and then the problem was partially solved:

`std::map<String, TEdit*> m_Edits;`

[image]

I say partially solved because I need to use `std::unordered_map` to have better performance, as I will pack lots of `TComponent`s later, so it will perform worst if I use `std::map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`packLabels()` is searching for `TEdit` objects instead of `TLabel` objects, and is `dynamic_cast`'ing them to `TLabel`, which will fail but you are not checking for that condition, and so your `m_Labels` map ends up being filled with `NULL` pointers.

As such, `TextEditsToLabels()` exhibits *undefined behavior* because it is trying to access `TLabel` objects that do not exist in the `m_Labels` map, but you are not checking for that condition.  The map's `operator[]` will return a NULL pointer if the specified key does not exist.  Switching to `std::map` does not "partially solve" that problem.

You need to fix that `packLabels()` error, then the rest of the code you have shown *should* work fine, eg:

```
void Container:: packLabels(){
    //String Labels[4] = {"Edit1", "Edit2", "Edit3", "Edit4"};
    String Labels[4] = {"Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4"}; // <-- HERE

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        m_Labels.insert(std::make_pair(Labels[i], dynamic_cast<TLabel*>(m_Form->FindComponent(Labels[i]))));
    }
}
```

You are also not checking whether `FindComponent()` is returning a NULL pointer before inserting into your maps. You should fix that as well, eg:

```cpp
void Container::packEdits(){
    String Edits[4] = {"Edit1", "Edit2", "Edit3", "Edit4"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        TComponent* comp = m_Form->FindComponent(Edits[i]);
        if (comp) {
            m_Edits.insert(std::make_pair(Edits[i], static_cast<TEdit*>(comp)));
        }
    }
}

void Container:: packLabels(){
    String Labels[4] = {"Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        TComponent* comp = m_Form->FindComponent(Labels[i]);
        if (comp) {
            m_Labels.insert(std::make_pair(Labels[i], static_cast<TLabel*>(comp)));
        }
    }
}
```

---

On a side note: your code is using pointers in places that really should be using references instead.

I would suggest changing the code to be more like the following instead:

Test.h

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef TestH
#define TestH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "Container.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TUMap_Test : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TEdit *Edit1;
    TEdit *Edit2;
    TEdit *Edit3;
    TEdit *Edit4;

    TLabel *Label1;
    TLabel *Label2;
    TLabel *Label3;
    TLabel *Label4;

    TButton *Button1;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);

private:    // User declarations
    Container Cont;

public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TUMap_Test(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TUMap_Test *UMap_Test;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Test.cpp

```cpp
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Test.h"
#include "Handler.h"

#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"

TUMap_Test *UMap_Test;

fastcall TUMap_Test::TUMap_Test(TComponent* Owner): TForm(Owner), Cont(this) {
    Cont.packComponents();
}

void __fastcall TUMap_Test::Button1Click(TObject *Sender){
    TextEditsToLabels(Cont);
}
```

Container.h

```cpp
#ifndef ContainerH
#define ContainerH

#include <vcl.h>
#include <unordered_map>

class Container{

private:

    TForm* m_Form;
    std::unordered_map<String, TEdit*> m_Edits;
    std::unordered_map<String, TLabel*> m_Labels;

    void packEdits();
    void packLabels();

public:
    Container(TForm* Form);
    void packComponents();

    std::unordered_map<String, TEdit*>& getEdits();
    std::unordered_map<String, TLabel*>& getLabels();

    /* alternatively:
    TEdit* getEdit(String Name);
    TLabel* getLabel(String Name);
    */
};

#endif
```

Container.cpp

```cpp
#include "Container.h"

Container::Container(TForm* Form) {
    m_Form = Form;
}

void Container::packComponents() {
    packEdits();
    packLabels();
}

void Container::packEdits() {
    String Edits[4] = {"Edit1", "Edit2", "Edit3", "Edit4"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        TComponent *comp = m_Form->FindComponent(Edits[i]);
        TEdit *edit = dynamic_cast<TEdit*>(comp);
        if (edit) {
            m_Edits[Edits[i]] = edit;
        }
    }
}

void Container::packLabels() {
    String Labels[4] = {"Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        TComponent* comp = m_Form->FindComponent(Labels[i]);
        TLabel *label = dynamic_cast<TLabel*>(comp);
        if (label) {
            m_Labels[Labels[i]] = label;
        }
    }
}

std::unordered_map<String, TEdit*>& Container::getEdits() {
    return m_Edits;
}

std::unordered_map<String, TLabel*>& Container::getLabels() {
    return m_Labels;
}

/* alternatively:
TEdit* Container::getEdit(String Name) {
    return m_Edits.at(Name);
}

TLabel* Container::getLabel(String Name) {
    return m_Labels.at(Name);
}
*/
```

Handler.h

```cpp
#ifndef HandlerH
#define HandlerH

#include "Container.h"

void TextEditsToLabels(Container& Cont);

#endif
```

Handler.cpp

```
#include "Handler.h"

static String getEditText(TEdit* edit) {
    if (edit) {
        return edit->Text;
    }
    return EmptyStr;
} 

static void TextEditToLabel(TEdit* edit, TLabel* label) {
    if ((edit) && (label)) {
        label->Caption = edit->Text;
    }
} 

void TextEditsToLabels(Container& Cont) {
    std::unordered_map<String, TEdit*>& edits = Cont.getEdits();
    std::unordered_map<String, TLabel*>& labels = Cont.getLabels();

    String Text1 = getEditText(edits["Edit1"]);
    String Text2 = getEditText(edits["Edit2"]);
    String Text3 = getEditText(edits["Edit3"]);
    String Text4 = getEditText(edits["Edit4"]);

    //BREAKPOINT

    //Change the Caption of Labels to Edits Text
    TextEditToLabel(edits["Edit1"], labels["Label1"]);
    TextEditToLabel(edits["Edit2"], labels["Label2"]);
    TextEditToLabel(edits["Edit3"], labels["Label3"]);
    TextEditToLabel(edits["Edit4"], labels["Label4"]);

    /* alternatively:

    String Text1 = Cont.getEdit("Edit1")->Text;
    String Text2 = Cont.getEdit("Edit2")->Text;
    String Text3 = Cont.getEdit("Edit3")->Text;
    String Text4 = Cont.getEdit("Edit4")->Text;

    //BREAKPOINT

    //Change the Caption of Labels to Edits Text
    Cont.getLabel("Label1")->Caption = Cont.getEdit("Edit1")->Text;
    Cont.getLabel("Label2")->Caption = Cont.getEdit("Edit2")->Text;
    Cont.getLabel("Label3")->Caption = Cont.getEdit("Edit3")->Text;
    Cont.getLabel("Label4")->Caption = Cont.getEdit("Edit4")->Text;
    */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have fixed packComponents function, but I got the same problem, Even I tried to paste your code exactly as you wrote. I got the same problem on the breakpoint, NULL values.

I have added Test.cpp file to my Question post.

Comment: Then you are just going to have to debug the entire code from start to end to make sure every step is acting as expected. Make sure every object is being created correctly, every pointer is being assigned correctly, etc. There has to be something going on that you are not accounting for.

Comment: I have debugged using an iterator for loop, in order to get the Text on each Edits packet on the unordered_map. Were tested inside packEdits(), packLabels(), getEdits(), Button1Click() functions. Acting as expected. Then when the Container Object goes into TextEditToLabel() function is where the problem still remaining. NULL VALUES on Edits and Labels

Comment: That suggests to me that either the Container itself, or the TEdit pointers inside of it, are different when inside of TextEditsToLabel() than when in anywhere else. Use the debugger to check that. The memory addresses should be consistent everywhere.

Comment: after debugging, I traced the address of TEdit1 on each function, even inside TextEditsToLabels() function, Local Variables viewer always showed me the same adress ({ { u"Edit1" }, :00FE23F0 }). The memory addresses was consistent. This is so weird, because with map works but not with unordered_map.

Comment: @Loststar which version of C++Builder are you using? And, which compiler (classic vs clang, 32bit vs 64bit, etc)?

Comment: Hi @Remy, I'm using C++ Builder 10.4 CE version, Borland Resource Compiler (brcc32.exe), win 32bit

Comment: @Loststar "*Borland Resource Compiler (brcc32.exe)*" is not one of the available [**C++** compilers](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Compilers).

Comment: I have no changed any configuration about compilers, so the compiler that is set is as defauld. I don't know how to check wich compiler I have.

Comment: @Loststar check the [C++ Compiler](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Compiler) project option, is "Use 'classic' Borland compiler" set to True or False? And, in the Project Manager, are you compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit Windows? Compiling for Win64 uses a clang compiler only. Compiling for Win32 may use either the Borland compiler or a clang compiler.

Comment: -"Use 'classic' Borland compiler" is set to False (uncheked).
-Is compiling for Win32

Comment: @Loststar Then you clearly changed your config at some point, because that option is enabled by default. In any case, you are using one of the 32bit clang compilers. Do you have the same problem if you turn on the classic compiler and recompile the project? If the problem goes away, then this is likely a bug in the clang compiler or its STL and would need to be [reported to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: I have set as true "Use 'classic' Borland compiler". Then after run the program, error messages showed me errors, all of them are relaed with unordered_map.

'unordered_map' is not member of 'std' & "declaration terminated incorrectly"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253935/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-loststar).